# Аrrangement of functions in relation to the object

Tags: python, function, object

For what reason some functions are set after the dot and some are not?
For instance:

```
number = '150'
alist = number.split()
a2ndlist = int(number)
```

The same object, but different arrangements. I'm just wondering.

My guess is related to Python's class and object system, but I can't be sure.

Comment: yes, your guess is right. use `dir(number)` to find out those that the object supports

Comment: `int(number)` means that there is a global function called `int` that I'm passing a value to.  `number.split()` means that that `number` has attached to it a function called `split()`, and I'm to call it.   Different objects could have different `split()` methods attached to them.

Answer (score 0):

Dot notation
is used when calling a method that is associated with an object. The method is invoked on the object and usually operates on the data contained within that object.

Non-dot notation
is used when calling a function that is not bound to a specific object. It typically takes the object as an argument and performs some operation on it.

Comment: *"It typically takes the object as an argument and performs some operation on it."* - In this example, yes, but it depends on the function. E.g. `int()` can also take no arguments and return `0`.

Comment: It's worth clarifying that dot notation is also used when accessing a function of a module.